# Changing variable type of R dataframe inside a list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a list of dataframes and I need to transform a certain variable in each of the dataframes as factor.

E.g.

```
 myList <- list(df1 = data.frame(A = sample(10), B = rep(1:2, 10)),
                df2 = data.frame(A = sample(10), B = rep(1:2, 10))
                )
```

Lets say that variable B needs to be factor in each dataframe. I've tried this:

```
 TMP <- setNames(lapply(seq_along(myList), function(x) apply(myList[[x]][c("B")], 2, factor)), names(myList))
```

but it only returns the transformed variable, not the whole dataframe as I need. I know how to do this with for loop, but I don't want to resort to that.

Comment: Something like `TMP <- lapply(myList, function(x) {x[, "B"] <- factor(x[, "B"]) ; x}) ; str(TMP)` probably

Answer (score 0):

Per comment from David Arenburg, this solution should work:

```
TMP <- lapply(myList, function(x) {x[, "B"] <- factor(x[, "B"]) ; x}) ; str(TMP)
```